# Show/Hide div with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a a HTML page with a button which shoes hidden content when pressed. I am using jquery code which I have bundled into my HTML page. When I press the button to show the content in the hidden div it works find, however when I press the button again to hide the content nothing happens. If anyone could help me that would be great. Also how would I be able to target multiple buttons. Would I just paste the same jquery code and label it '2' and then '3' and so on for example? Any working examples would be great. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#spoiler1").hide();

            $("#button1").click(function() {
                $("#spoiler1").show(300);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<button id="button1">Adventurer &#x25BC;</button>

<div id="spoiler1" style="display:none">
    <p>1. Climb a tree<input type="checkbox" /></p>
    <p>2. Roll down a really big hill<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>3. Camp out in the wild<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>4. Build a den<input type="checkbox" ></p>
    <p>5. Skim a stone<input type="checkbox" ></p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: _"however when I press the button again to hide the content nothing happens"_. Why should it? All your code does is show a div on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spoiler1").hide();
$("#button1").click(function(){
    if($("#spoiler1").is(':visible')){
       $("#spoiler1").slideUp(300);
       }
       else
       {
       $("#spoiler1").slideDown(300);
       }
});
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/YvUDV/

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#spoiler1").hide();

    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $("#spoiler1").toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SA52V/)

**Update**

And the idea about having mutiple buttons, I've come up with the approach that you should try, use `classes` instead of `IDs` for the buttons and provide the same `ID` to `divs` that you want to toggle. This might take some design issues but you can manage and this is just a basic guideline to move forward.

As Markup is too long for mutiple divs so i'm posting only.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".category").click(function () {
        $(".show").hide();
        var divToShow = $(this).text().split(" ")[0];
        $("#" + divToShow).toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SA52V/1/)

Comment: I think Chrome has problems with hide() and show(). You will have to use $(selector).css('display', 'none') to hide and .css('display', 'block') to show.

Comment: @MarloC Chrome has nothing to do with `hide()` & `show()`, it will work fine  with any browser!

Comment: Just saying. I used to use show() and hide() until I found out it doesn't work in a particular browser. Can't remember if it was FF or Chrome. I didn't downvote you by the way.

Comment: @MarloC It's ok but `show()` and `.hide()` will work with any browser, i've never found it non-working in any browser.

Comment: Actually, it was a particular version of it. They updated it now and it works fine on the current version. I was developing a  site and had to use css('display', 'block'), etc. instead.

Answer (score 0):

As for multiple button event. Assign a class name to the button so you can select by class.

```
$('button.toggle-div').click(function(){...});
```

As for visibility toggle, there are a number of ways.

1. Use `toggle()` in `jQuery`. (the most obvious choice, but in practice we could also..)
2. Use `toggleClass()` [link](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to
   add/remove a class which has a `display:none` css rule. (more flexible, you can toggle other css styles like the font color, background, etc.)
3. Use some
   two-way binding JavaScript libraries like knockoutjs or angular.
   (Probably an overkill for a small application. But it will
   definitely reduce the amount of coding if it is a large scale.)

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle instead:

```
$('#button1').bind("click",function(){
    $("#spoiler1").toggle("fast");
});
```